# NSArray countByEnumeratingWithState sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, google-analytics-sdk

I'm getting this error:

With no stack trace.

`-[__NSArrayI countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance`

What would call this method?

Is it possible to pin down what's calling this? I have zombies on but don't see the caller.

Here's thread1:

[image: thread1 crash]

The only other clickable line is this from AFNetworking (`[runloop run]`). I just upgraded my AFNetworking pod.

```
+ (void)networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:(id)__unused object {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"AFNetworking"];

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];
    }
}
```

EDIT: The above breakpoint on `@autoreleasepool` was not even hit. I did find this in my code on the same crash in another thread (didn't see this last time):, on the `archiveSuccessful = line`

```
- (void)archiveContent:(BOOL)changeNotification userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    BOOL archiveSuccessful;
    @synchronized(self) {
        archiveSuccessful = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.contentDictionary toFile:self.filePath];
    }
    if (archiveSuccessful) {
        if(changeNotification && self.contentChangedNotificationName) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:self.contentChangedNotificationName object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        }
    } else {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Saving archive to %@ was not successful", self.filePath);
    }
}
```

This is called by

```
- (void)addObjects:(NSArray *)objects changeNotification:(BOOL)changeNotification {
    [objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([obj conformsToProtocol:NSProtocolFromString(@"DRLocalObject")]) {
            [self addObject:obj changeNotification:NO];
        }
    }];
```

debugger printouts from the `[self addObject...` line

```
(lldb) po obj
0x00007fde0ff56770

(lldb) po 0x00007fde0ff56770
140591727208304
```

EDIT:

`threadMain:` called  from Google analytics. A project find & quick open shows no selector named `threadMain:`

[image]

Comment: That's called when you do a fast enumeration on an array.

Comment: as in for (myobject *f in myArray)? What code can I search for to find it in the project?

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint to see if it pinpoints the offending line?

Comment: Yes, I have all exceptions breakpoint.

Comment: Stack trace message is descriptive enough to tell you that your are call countByEnumeratingWithState on deallocated instance. Please check how the deallocation is possible?

Comment: Can you paste the stack when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Pasted.. it gives me nothing to click on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion --  @jeffamaphone I have isolated the crash to that runLoop run line. Now to debug what's causing it! Is there any way to see the context of this crash.. ?

Comment: EDIT: this is not the crash, I didn't hit my breakpoint there testing another time -- it's just where the thread happened to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a very hard kind of bug to debug via StackOverflow, so I'm just giving pointers here.)

You almost certainly are modifying some data structure on multiple threads. Given the specifics, I suspect there's an array that is an ivar of some object that you drop on one thread while you're enumerating over it on some other thread. You drop it either by deallocating the owning object, or by replacing the array.

The fact that you're calling `@synchronized(self)` strongly suggests that you're doing dangerous threading in this program. In modern ObjC, `@synchronized` is almost never the right tool. If you're using `NSThread` directly, that is probably also a source of your troubles (AFNetworking is old enough to get a pass on this, but you should not copy their approach). The right tool for handling concurrency is either GCD (`dispatch_*`) or `NSOperation`.

Have you verified that every mutation of `self.contentDictionary` and `self.filePath` is also synchronized. I would particularly be suspicious of `self.contentDictionary` because it is the kind of thing that might have arrays in it.

Kudos on correctly using accessors here BTW, though if they're not atomic, it is possible to get inconsistent state on them if you read and write them on different threads. Making them atomic does not make them fully thread safe; you still really need to be using something like GCD or `NSOperation` to serialize access.

The fact that you call `@synchronized` and then post a notification in the same method is also somewhat suspicious. Notifications synchronously process on the same thread that they are posted on, so your notification observers need to be aware of what thread they may be called on.

Note that crashing in the AFNetworking runloop processing method is meaningless. That's giving you no real hints.

I would look to your threading. Look particularly for unprotected access to arrays (and particularly array properties). And make sure that you serialize all your accesses with GCD or `NSOperation`, not `@synchronize`.

Comment: Thank you for your pointers. There are several threads of asynchronous dispatches called when a user logs in to fetch their profile data. I will investigate the use of @synchronized in the app and see what it takes to use dispatch to update that.

Comment: Rob, I do see a threadMain: being called from Google Analytics. Perhaps that is calling NSThread? Updated post with stack trace.

Comment: what accessors were you referring to here? Inside the enumeration block?

Comment: The GAI stuff likely isn't the issue. I suspect it's a cross-thread access inside your code. By accessors, I meant the use of `self.contentDictionary` rather than `_contentDictionary`. Being careful that way will help you make this thread-safe.

Comment: I stopped the crash, related to dismissing of a view controller at an inopportune time. Marking as correct for good tips about threading.